# Is it possible to create a binary classifier from bayesian network?

Tags: time-series, classification, binary-data, bayesian-network, dynamic-regression

I have a labeled data set consisting of longitudinal data and I would like to train a dynamic bayesian network. The output should be probability of the observation being 1 in a selected step given the evidence. Does this make any sense? I am new to probabilistic models.

EDIT from comment: more details on the problem

I need an interpretable model, I want to know why did the probability of label switching from 0 to 1 changed compared to previous estimates for the specific individual and why is it higher/lower compared to other individuals. Regarding data: I have groupped individuals for which I have multiple observations of multiple features in time. there is a seasonal trend in some variables, which is different for groups of individuals. More details about the data: [Which algorithm suits for classification of multivariate time series data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/489088/which-algorithm-suits-for-classification-of-multivariate-time-series-data?noredirect=1#comment903184_489088)

Comment: Of course you can. What in particular makes you want to use a bayesian network, over say just a standard off the shelf regression method?

Comment: I want to construct a model which gives me the dependencies between variables and study the structure while making predictions, not only measure effects of the variables as in regression.

Comment: To get an interesting answer, you need to give us more context of your application! Why do you need to model dependencies between predictor variables if your goal is to predict probabilities?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I need an interpretable model, I want to know why did the probability of label switching from 0 to 1 changed compared to previous estimates for the specific individual and why is it higher/lower compared to other individuals. Regarding data: I have groupped individuals for which I have multiple observations of multiple features in time. there is a seasonal trend in some variables, which is different for groups of individuals.

Comment: I have summarized the problem in more details here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/489088/which-algorithm-suits-for-classification-of-multivariate-time-series-data?noredirect=1#comment903184_489088

Comment: Can you please add this new information as an edit to your post? Not everybody reads comments ...