# Which algorithm suits for classification of multivariate time series data?

Tags: time-series, survival, bayesian-network, compositional-data, probabilistic-forecasts

I have multivariate time series data, where the goal is to predict a binary label, which is changing in time. For illustration: there are 20 individuals, for each of them I measure 50 values (categorical, compositional and continuous types) each day, for 1000 consecutive days (some individuals came into study after start, i.e. I do not have 1000 values for each of them and some left the study). There is one more variable, a binary label, which I assign to each individual at each day. Once the label becomes 1 it is hard to get back to 0, but not impossible.

The goal is to predict the probability of the label being 1 in next 1,2,3, ... days for each individual and at the same be able to say which of the 50 variables contributed to this probability of label being 1 and how much. Which model is suitable for this? I was thinking about dynamic Bayesian networks, but I am not sure whether this makes sense, as I do not believe that the data have Markovian property and this assumption would be thus incorrect. I was also thinking about some survival model, as I have left and right censoring, but I am not very good in it.

Please, if you have any clue what I am talking about, give me some input, I am out of ideas ...

Comment: Im no expert on the field, but based on what you say, I think that your best option would be a cox regression (a type of survival model) in which you add a lasso-based regularization to ensure sparsity and select the variables that most contributed to the probability. A quick search on google yielded this R package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/vignettes/Coxnet.pdf but there are maybe other options.

Comment: @ÁlvaroMéndezCivieta thanks for the suggestion. This is one of my ideas as well, Moreover I would like to incorporate random effects for each individual to the survival model, in order not to loose information in past observations. However this should maybe be modelled as a time-series (I know that there are seasonal effects in some individuals), but this seems too complicated for me so I am looking also for more ideas.

Comment: in terms of prediction you can always use a recurrent neural network and it will probably give you the best level of prediction, not sure if you will get much meaning out of the parameters though

Comment: Not quite sure what your question is (or if you really have one) we can't give you a definitive answer without having the data and exploring it. You seem keen on a bayesian network...I would suggest just implementing it and seeing how far it gets you, what road blocks you encounter etc. When you have a more concrete question then you can come back here and ask it.